# Sample app required with rails mysql and apache

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, apache

I want a sample application which is of Rails and the database Mysql and the server Apache.
Please let me know if any such application is available.
Thanks in advance

I am using Opensolaris machine.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Windows, you can start with InstantRails which comes with some sample applications. It also makes it really easy to start with rails. It has apache / mysql inbuilt. (Though rails doesn't really care what DB or server you are using)
[instantrails.rubyforge.org](http://instantrails.rubyforge.org)

Comment: I am using Opensolaris machine.